# Why and how to solve SharedArrayBuffer warning in my react-app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, sharedarraybuffer

My React-app has `axios` (dependency) and `json-server` (dev-dependency) insatlled, after I did this, *my react-app started throwing the following warning message*:

> **`[Deprecation] SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021.`**

What is this, how do i resolve the error and why is this happening?

I'm a beginner in the filed and the link provided in the error is using high-level language which I cannot understand, [this](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/) is the link provided in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What it is?** - Chrome will require cross-origin isolation starting version 91 in order to use SharedArrayBuffer.

**Solution:** You just need to update the `react` and `react-dom` versions from `17.0.1` to `17.0.2`.

You can use `yarn upgrade react --latest` and `yarn upgrade react-dom --latest` to upgrade and update the package.json. Also, please restart the server after updating npm packages.

---

**What is SharedArrayBuffer and why the change?** [Official Doc](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/03/sharedarraybuffer-notes)

`SharedArrayBuffer` is a `JavaScript` object to share a memory space across threads on a website. It was used by websites before the vulnerability called [Spectre](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/meltdown-spectre) was found. However, because Spectre was a CPU level vulnerability and it's unlikely to be fixed in the foreseeable future, browsers decided to disable the SharedArrayBuffer object.

While Chrome re-enabled it on the desktop with Site Isolation as a temporary remedy, `cross-origin isolation` was standardized as a way to safely enable the SharedArrayBuffer object. Starting with version 91, planned to be released in late May 2021, Chrome will gate the SharedArrayBuffer object behind cross-origin isolation. Firefox enabled the SharedArrayBuffer obje

Comment: thanks for the reply, what is sharedArraybuffer?

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope that helps. SharedArrayBuffer is a JavaScript object to share a memory space across threads on a website.

Answer (score 2):

I am still having this warning message after updating my react to 17.0.2. Any recommendations? thank you

Comment: did you update react and react-dom both? as they are different dependencies

Comment: Yes, I did. They are even 17.0.3

Comment: Yeah same here, I did update both to 17.0.2, but I'm still facing this warning.